# python max negative values

Tags: python, python-3.x

While entering the negative numbers as below, I want to extract the max value. I expect that value to be `-0.123`, but the actual value (in Python 3.6.0 shell) is `-45.02`. Here is my code:

```
x=input("Enter value of X :")
y=input("Enter value of y :")
Z=input("Enter value of Z :")

print("Display of max value")
print(max(x,y,Z))
```

input("Please press enter to exit")

And its output:

```
Enter value of X :-45.02
Enter value of y :-0.123
Enter value of Z :-1.136
Display of max value
-45.02
```

Can you help me figure out that result?

Comment: You're comparing strings using lexicographic order, when you want to be comparing numbers instead. Convert your inputs to `float`s before taking the `max`.

Answer (score 3):

As @MarkDickinson says, you have to convert to floats to compare numbers. If you don't the numbers are compared as strings (`"10"` comes before `"7"` for example because it compares one character at a time; in this case `"1"` and `"7"`). So try this:

```
try:    
    x=float(input("Enter value of X :"))
    y=float(input("Enter value of y :"))
    Z=float(input("Enter value of Z :"))
except ValueError:
    print('Could not convert to float!')
    exit()  
else:
    print("Display of max value:", max(x,y,Z))
```

---

In your case, comparing `"-0.123"` with `"-45.02"`:

The `"-"` gets neglected because it is common and it then boils down to finding the max of `"0"` and `"4"` which is of course `"4"`. As a result, `"-45.02"` is the max of the two.